# Как поменять отступ между строками в VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как поменять расстояние между строками в visual studio code? (не табуляция)

Comment: Никогда не думал, что есть такая настройка, а она есть `"editor.lineHeight"`

Comment: Спасибо, все работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надо `"editor.lineHeight": <число>,` в settings.json добавить.
Спасибо человеку в комментариях

Answer (score 0):

Зайди в Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Line spacing измени на нужное значение.